# Possible to get Visual Studio's IDE Colors in Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to obtain the currently used colors (not Theme names) being used in the Visual Studio IDE from within a VS Extension? I have an extension in which I would like to list the exact colors for things like text, background of panels, etc.

Comment: Hi, you can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

The crucial thing is the **[VSColorTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.vscolortheme?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)**:

[image]

You could use this to get the specific color:

```
var backgroundColor = VSColorTheme.GetThemedColor(EnvironmentColors.ToolWindowBackgroundColorKey);
```

The above is just a sample. There are various colors defined in the **[EnvironmentColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.environmentcolors?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)** definition:

[image]

You can develop based on the above official SDK documents I shared.

You can also refer to this official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/colors-and-styling-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#accessing-the-service

Comment: Thank you, that works for what I'm doing!

Comment: @SamMarrocco Hi Sam, since my answer works, could you please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question? This will be helpful to others who have similar questions and seeking answers. :)